# About login a web site by Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a problem to be solved here, I've been plagued by it for two days.
I want to use Python to visit website and obtain the number of unread messages, but obviously there are some small problems. I just see "guest" page,not correct logged page.

Please help me find out where my problem is, my code is as following.

```
import requests
import os
import re
#import time

header_info ={
'Host': 'weavi.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Referer': 'https://weavi.com/',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',}


myS = requests.session()

r= myS.get("https://weavi.com")

myCookies= r.cookies

XSRF= re.findall('name="csrf-param" />\n<meta content=".+?" name="csrf-token" />',r.text,re.S)

XSRF_str= XSRF[0][36:-22]

login_data = {'username':'sera***@gmail.com','password':'***1230','redirect':'https://weavi.com/','authenticity_token':XSRF_str}

myS.post("https://weavi.com",data=login_data,headers=header_info,cookies=myCookies)

r=myS.get("https://weavi.com/")

message = re.findall('unread_message',r.text,re.S)

print message
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: for a start, you need to grab the cookies you get from the login post request and pass those to your final get request (Assuming *weavi* uses cookies to maintain session state)

Comment: BTW, there is a typo here: name="csrf-oken"

Comment: I just see "guest" page,not correct logged page

Comment: Thanks,but I still could not got correct data.

Answer (score 0):

The form in the website POST to `/login`:

```
<form id="hidden-login-form" method="post" action="/login" style="display: none;">
```

So try:

```
myS.post("https://weavi.com/login",data=login_data,headers=header_info,cookies=myCookies)
```

I don't have a valid account to test, so please let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: I still got no message,and if you need account kindly ,please try vasilyluan@gmail.com / W03211230.

Comment: Sorry,the account is"Vasilyluan@gmail.com"